# Reindex data by exec shell command root file goes 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: magento-1.7, reindex

I have tried with below script

```
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app('en');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$indexer="shell/indexer.php";
if(file_exists($indexer))
{

                $idxlist=array("catalog_product_attribute",
                               "catalog_product_price",
                               "catalog_product_flat",
                               "catalog_category_flat",
                               "catalog_category_product",
                               "catalog_url",
                               "catalogsearch_fulltext",
                               "cataloginventory_stock");
        //reindex using magento command line
        foreach($idxlist as $idx)
        {
            echo "reindex $idx n ";
            exec("php shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx");
        }
}
```

Since my store has more than 3000 products,After ran this script from root folder,it goes 504 gateway timeout error. Any possibility to print the output with out time error ?

Please advice

Comment: I gather you are calling this from a web browser? If that is the case, the timeout error is because your webserver (apache) is set to only allow a script to process for x seconds. Why are you doing a re-index like this anyways?

Comment: probably he has no access to the shell itself :) ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);   or ask your admin about your limits.

Comment: @ProxiBlue Since my client could not ran reindex from admin end. I ran successfully via shell command.SO i tried shell command with separate script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still going to incur your Apache/Nginx timeout if you're running this over HTTP.

I would personally suggest running the operation directly in command line but if that's unsuitable you could run your exec() command in the background.

```
 exec("php shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

Will remove the output and run the command in another process causing your timeout to not exist. Obviously this means the script will believe it's completed straight away. This will also hide the normal and error output.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete

Comment: Excellent :) It Works in background after update this exec and when i see index management grid.I can see processing one by one and finish the execution :)

Comment: @Dinesh glad it worked! If you want to get more involved you can write the output to a file and periodically check it for changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process/45966#45966

Comment: how do we write same shell command here exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));

Comment: I tried with             exec(sprintf("php shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
var_dump($pidfile); It always null

Comment: You need to define $outputfile and $pidfile as variables above the command. These are files on the filesystem.

Comment: okay let me create text file and assign the file path to respective variables and try run